# Fading out divs and replacing with one

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

This probably has been asked numerous times (I just couldn't find it).

I have four links which all correspond to their own "div" with information in it. What I want to happen is (the first div is displayed by default), click on the second link and the first fades out and the second div fades in (at the same spot of the other). I got the fade in/out working (in a sense), but they all just stack up and do some weird movement. I would appreciate any help. I have placed a test file on jsfiddle. My jquery probably is a bit screwy as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/buScL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your fading effects are all trying to happen at the same time.  Using callbacks, you can control the order more strictly.  See this **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvv9R/)**, or the identical code below.  Why the ugliness when the fades happen at the same time?  The blocks are naturally stacked according to the normal flow.  When one is in the process of fading out, it still takes up space in the flow.  It only releases that space at the very end of the fade, when `display:none` goes into effect.  When the replacement box is fading it, it gets positioned below where it would normally belong until that final space release.  That's when it pops back up to the top in an ugly way.  Check out jQuery's documentation on [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) and check out the callback section (fadeIn and fadeOut work the same way).

```
<div id="hello"> hello world! </div>
<div id="goodbye"> goodbye world! </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 ​$("#hello").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeToggle("slow", function(){
           $("#goodbye").fadeToggle("slow"); //Here is a callback
        });           
    });


$("#goodbye").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeToggle("slow", function(){
       $("#hello").fadeToggle("slow") //Here is a callback
    }) ;             
});
    ​
```

css:

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#hello{
    background-color:red  ; 
}

#goodbye{
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding absolute position to divs should fix this .You should also consider using class for fading out other divs . It just makes code look better .

http://jsfiddle.net/mTKFJ/

Answer (score 0):

Give all of the divs a class and then `positon:absolute;`

This causes them to all be one on top of the other so when you fade out/in, it happens in the same place.

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/buScL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text of the anchors for select the targets, try the following:

```
  $("#controlls a").click(function () {
      var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', "")
      $('#'+id).fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut()
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/buScL/12/)

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like following:

***HTML***

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <ul id="controlls">  
      <li><a href="#" id="one" class="dealer">Dealer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="two" class="advertise">Advertise</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="three" class="social">Social Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="four" class="need">Need</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="slider">
        <div id="dealer">
            <p>If you click on this paragraph
              you'll see it just fade away.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="advertise">
            <p>If you click on this paragraph
            you'll see it just fade away.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="social">
            <p>If you click on this paragraph
            you'll see it just fade away.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="need">
            <p>If you click on this paragraph
            you'll see it just fade away.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use following jQuery code:

***jQuery***

```
$("#controlls li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('class'); // get class of clicked anchor tag
    // first fadeOut the visible div
    $('#slider div:visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
        // after fadeOut complete show target div
        $('div#' + id).fadeIn();
    })
});
```

#### [Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/buScL/13/)

#### Note

Here, you've to make the `fadeIn()` within the `fadeOut()` callback function, so that `fadeIn()` will happen just after `fadeOut()`.